# Problem understanding the word “collect” in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I began to read the original version of Harry Potter recently. But I got stuck at the very beginning: I don't understand the meaning of the following line which appears in the first chapter of The Philosopher's Stone:

> this was probably some silly stunt — these people were obviously collecting for something

After checking it out in several translations, I found that even translators don't have a consensus about its meaning! One translation tell me it means "these people were gathering together for some special and silly purpose", while for another translation, "these people were collecting money for some strange charitable purpose".

The thing is, both translation are compatible with what I get when looking up "collect" in dictionaries. It seems that 'collect' has the following 2 meanings applicable here as an intransitive verb: 1)to assemble, as in " A crowd soon collected at the scene of the the accident"; 2)to obtain (money or contribution) from a number of people or places, as in "He's collecting for famine relief".

How can one exclude one of the above explanation, leaving the other the only possibility?

**EDIT:** @Adam has pointed out that the text two paragraphs below:

> He'd forgotten all about the people in coats until he passed a group of them next to the baker's. He eyed them angrily as he passed. He didn't know why, but they made him uneasy. This bunch were whispering excitedly, too, and he couldn't see a single collecting tin.

implies that here "collecting" should mean "collecting money or contribution". That's a good point, but is there any more direct way that we can turn to decide the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: In practice I'd say this verb use of ***collect*** is effectively a "back-formation" from *[have a] **collection** [for X]* (ask people to donate money to X). An Oxfam fundraiser might feasibly say *I collect for Oxfam*, but I can't really imagine a "freelance fundraiser" (someone who does this on behalf of many charities, but doesn't want to name them) saying something like *What do I do for a job? I collect* (except maybe facetiously). But they might well say *I organise collections*, which would be easily understood.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. So can I assume that when "collect" arrise without an object, it will mean "raising money"?

Comment: @Censi LI: As implied by my earlier comment, you'll probably ***never*** have to make that assumption, because you're not likely to ever come across ***collect** [donations]* used in this way without some kind of "object" being explicitly stated. The primary "direct" object *(money, donations, contributions, etc.)* is often omitted, as in your cited example, but even there the "indirect object" *(for **something**)* is at least *syntactically* present. Don't forget that people also collect things like old clothes for charity, not just money.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry but I'm still a bit confused... Do you mean that the object of "collect" can be omitted, in this case the object could be money or other things, and we need not specify it, but it always implies that the object is collected as donation?

Comment: I'm sure less than 1 in 1000 instances of the verb "collect" will be for this highly specific sense. So to repeat myself - there's probably no need to you to "learn" precisely how to use it at all. In the remote eventuality that you come across a sentence like *I saw some Rag Week students collecting in the high street* you can just assume an implied *collecting **[charity] donations** [for some good cause]*, but usually the speaker/writer would have used something like *collecting **for charity*** anyway. Don't over-think this one - it's not very useful to many other contexts.

Comment: I'm happy to keep plugging away with clarifications until we get where we want to be, but even now I'm not exactly sure how to write a good Answer for your question. I've been saying your "not-very-explicit" example is a fairly uncommon usage that maybe doesn't justify too much attention. But on reflection, suppose the text had been *...these people were obviously **demonstrating*** (which might of might not be followed by ***against something***). Would you have understood that straight away? What about *now?*

Comment: The other piece of context that is relevant is found one paragraph later, as Dursley passes the group again:  _"He’d forgotten all about the people in cloaks until he passed a group of them next to the baker’s. He eyed them angrily as he passed. He didn’t know why, but they made him uneasy. This bunch were whispering excitedly, too, and **he couldn’t see a single collecting tin."**_  A _"collecting tin"_ is the little pail that someone collecting for charity might ask donations to be dropped into.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I can understand the "demonstrating" case, but for the original "collecting" case, what really bothers me is that, when looking up the meaning of "collect" as an intransitive verb, I get two: the first is "assemble", like "A crowd soon collected at the scene of the the accident": the second is "obtain (money or contribution) from a number of people or places", but I have trouble figuring out what in this particular case has pinned down the meaning of "collecting" to the one instead of another, be it the context or some general rule about usage of the word.

Comment: @Censi LI: Most English words have a range of meanings that overlap to a greater or lesser extent. I don't see why you single out ***collect** = 1:to receive or compel payment, 2:assemble together* as a particularly confusing "overlap", but you don't seem to have a problem with ***demonstrate** = 1:describe, explain, or illustrate by example, 2:take part in mass public protests*. In both cases the possible alternative meanings are well-known, and *context* nearly always makes it obvious which sense applies in any given situation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers While I agree that in the "demonstrate" case the context excludes the alternative meanings, in the "collect" sense I find both meanings in this context seem very rational... This is where I got stuck before. Now, I tend to accept the view of Tim Pederick, that the first using of "coleect" is obsolete. Anyway, thanks a lot for your patience and your participation.

Comment: I see nothing "obsolete" about usages such as [a trio of drunks collected around a fire hydrant](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+trio+of+drunks+collected+around+a+fire+hydrant%22), and although I think it's probably *unlikely*, I certainly wouldn't rule out the possibility that Rowling in your cited context consciously and deliberately allowed / created a certain amount of *allusion* (not really "ambiguity") with her usage. She's a pretty careful writer overall, even though her primary concern must always be to ensure that (native speaker) *children* should understand her text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It is definitely "collecting money"

In British English (among others), "collecting [for something]" is an idiomatic phrase meaning "collecting monetary donations".

While I am a native speaker of Australian English, not British, I am very confident that this is the author's sole intended meaning. I do not agree with [Brillig's opinion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/135944/6120) that this is an intentional double meaning. Using "collect" of people getting themselves together in a group is, in my experience, vanishingly rare, despite related terms like "collective".

Sadly, I must conclude that one of the two translations you checked (well done on that, by the way) was simply wrong.

Answer (score -2):

The actual answer is that this interesting phrase creates a **double meaning**, or two valid meanings at once.  **Collecting money is the primary meaning.**  However, the author uses specific wording that is vague enough that *collecting* actually can work with both meanings.  Mr. Dursley sees people who are oddly-dressed, and naturally concludes that they are *collecting for some purpose* but, also, at the same time, speculates that the purpose is *an intention to collect money*.  The sort of unconventional language of the author, not specifically saying the more common *collecting money for something*, was probably specifically done to create this *double meaning*.

A *double meaning* is a literary device that one sees quite often especially in works of fiction from better writers.  The wording could also have been: *they were obviously collecting to be collecting for something* or it could have been *they were obviously collecting for something to be collected.* Neither of these alterations changes the meaning of what was written at all. But I can only make these alterations without changing the meaning of the text because there is a double meaning of collecting as I described.

In this case you need to provide the surrounding text for context.  I found:

> As he sat in the usual morning traffic jam, he couldn't help noticing
>   that there seemed to be a lot of strangely dressed people about.
>   People in cloaks. Mr. Dursley couldn't bear people who dressed in
>   funny clothes -- the getups you saw on young people! He supposed this
>   was some stupid new fashion. He drummed his fingers on the steering
>   wheel and his eyes fell on a huddle of these weirdos standing quite
>   close by. They were whispering excitedly together. Mr. Dursley was
>   enraged to see that a couple of them weren't young at all; why, that
>   man had to be older than he was, and wearing an emerald-green cloak!
>   The nerve of him! But then it struck Mr. Dursley that this was
>   probably some silly stunt -- these people were obviously collecting
>   for something... yes, that would be it.

Given the surrounding text so far there are a lot of people who have similar odd-looking clothes on and therefore this supports *collecting* in its primary meaning when there is no object - that is [*to gather together; assemble*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/collect?s=t).  So far, there is not any active collection of money, clothes, etc. taking place.  The people don't approach him as he sits in his car and ask for contributions - they are just people that Mr. Dursley notices as an oddly-dressed group. Thus one of your translations you found gives this meaning of *collecting* and without the additional textual clues it seems valid enough.  However...

As @Adam pointed out there is an additional important clue two paragraphs down that I found [here](https://rewordify.com/index.php?u=gw0j3nmh98xk7q) (with @Adam's help).  The text two paragraphs down states:

> He'd forgotten all about the people in coats until he passed a group
>   of them next to the baker's. He eyed them angrily as he passed. He
>   didn't know why, but they made him uneasy. This bunch were whispering
>   excitedly, too, and he couldn't see a single collecting tin.

This additional clue makes it clear that Mr. Dursley initially believed that they were gathered together for the purpose of collecting money.

What is interesting is that therefore this is really a double meaning of *collecting*.  Mr. Dursley clearly understands that there are people *gathering together or collecting*, one definition, and also thinks that the purpose of their gathering together is *to collect money, or collecting*.  **Collecting money is the primary meaning.**  However, the author uses specific wording that is vague enough that *collecting* actually can work with both meanings.

Comment: Even with just the context that you provide, I would (and did) read it as Dursley trying to rationalize the weird assemblage by viewing it as a charity drive. This interpretation of Dursley's thoughts is confirmed one paragraph later, as Dursley passes the group again: _"He’d forgotten all about the people in cloaks until he passed a group of them next to the baker’s. He eyed them angrily as he passed. He didn’t know why, but they made him uneasy. This bunch were whispering excitedly, too, **and he couldn’t see a single collecting tin."**_

Comment: Hmm.  Disadvantage of the Internet.  I don't have the next paragraph on the page I happened to pull up.  I think I'll revise my answer.  Is this the entire next paragraph as you've quoted it?  I'll Google and try and find it.

Comment: The verb _collect_ is used here only in the sense of _taking a collection_ of money. There isn't even a whiff of the intransitive _collect_ here. My kids got it immediately when I asked them. _"It's like the Lions Club on Memorial Day stopping cars"_, quoth my lad. The first translator who tried to render the text into the OP's unspecified English language got it wrong. That's all. And while it's marvelous that the Potter books have inspired kids to read, if this is "quality literature", what do we call _Heart of Darkness_?

Comment: @P. E. Dant think of it this way. The wording could also have been: *they were obviously collecting to be collecting for something* or it could have been *they were obviously collecting for something to be collected.* Neither of these alterations changes the meaning of what was written **at all.** But I can only make these alterations without changing the meaning of the text because there is a double meaning of collecting as I described*.

Comment: @P. E. Dant also if we were watching a high school football game and I said to you *Watch how this quarterback reads the safeties and makes audibles at the line of scrimmage.  This is something that one sees in pro quarterbacks quite a bit actually* would you therefore claim that I had just said he was a better quarterback than Tom Brady?  I just want to know if you're consistent with your interpretations.  Because my interpretation would be that he is only exhibiting a single characteristic of pro QBs, not that he's better than Brady or even a pro QB himself.

Comment: As Mario Cuomo once said: _"Yes, and if I had two pieces of bread, and if I also had a slice of roastbeef, I would have a roastbeefsandwich."_ The question is very simple. One of the translators thought _collect_ was used here as the _intransitive_, probably because the translator was not an English speaker. It's clear from the text, subtext, and context that Rowling intended _collect_ only in the _transitive_ sense. Interpretation is enjoyable, but it isn't germane here.

Comment: Ok whatever.  I changed my answer to something in between your position and mine.  I hope you're happy with this compromise.  I agree that you are stating the primary meaning.  But the fact is there is a double meaning - the wording is vague enough that it does work with the other meaning as well - sorry if you can't recognize that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! While kind of controversy, your opinion present a new angle that I never thought of before, and thus valuable to me.